# Website with multiple pages on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I have spent some time creating a portfolio website using React Vite and have finally got it to where I can call it done. I know that Github can host your website for you if you make a repository under your user account named .github.io I did that and pushed my files onto the repository. The link generated worked I saw my website, well the homepage at least. When I clicked the navbar to navigate to other pages it threw an error 404. In the console I got the following errors:
[image: error]

Here is how I have the multiple pages navigation setup:

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.tsx";
import { createContext } from "react";
import useLocalStorage from "use-local-storage";
import "/src/styles/App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Home from "./components/Home.tsx";
import About from "./components/About.tsx";
import Skills from "./components/Skills.tsx";
import Resources from "./components/Resources.tsx";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.tsx";

export const ThemeContext = createContext("light");

function App() {
  const defaultDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage(
    "theme",
    defaultDark ? "dark" : "light"
  );

  const switchTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    setTheme(newTheme);
  };

  let Component;
  switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case "/":
      Component = <Home />;
      break;
    case "/about":
      Component = <About />;
      break;
    case "/skillsandprojects":
      Component = <Skills />;
      break;
    case "/resources":
      Component = <Resources />;
      break;
    case "/contact":
      Component = <Contact />;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div className="app" data-theme={theme}>
      <div className="top-container">
        <Navbar theme={theme} handleClick={switchTheme} />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        {window.location.pathname === "/resources" ? (
          <>
            <div className="AltLeft"></div>
            <div className="Middle"> {Component}</div>
            <div className="AltRight"></div>
            <div className="bottomEdge layer"></div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {window.location.pathname === "/" ? (
              <>
                {" "}
                <div className="AltLeft"></div>
                <div className="Middle"> {Component}</div>
                <div className="AltRight"></div>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                {" "}
                <div className="Left"></div>
                <div className="Middle"> {Component}</div>
                <div className="Right"></div>
              </>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I didn't use any extra library to change the page. Here is my navbar code:

```
import "/src/styles/Navbar.css";

interface Props {
  theme: string;
  handleClick: () => void;
}

function Navbar({ theme, handleClick }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="navbar-container">
      <div className="left-side" />
      <nav className="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/about">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/skillsandprojects">Skills/Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/resources">Resources</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div className="right-side">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Switch to {theme === "light" ? "Dark" : "Light"} Theme
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Here is my repo:

[repo](https://github.com/CohenK/CohenK.github.io/actions)

I looked up the issue and followed some solutions like adding base: "/repository name/" in the vite.config.ts file and   "homepage": "/repository name/#", in the package.json file, but none of them worked. Do I need a library to do this rather than just what I did or is there a simple fix like including some variables in my package.json or config files or maybe my pathnames for imports needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I followed a video tutorial online with routing multiple pages in react which involved adding entry points in the vite.config.ts file and also creating a new .html file for each page. This enabled the multi-page functionality to work.